# Multiple replacements using regular expressions in python

Tags: regular-expression, python

Can I use regex in python to have multiple types of substitutions? Like in this string "hello, this is me" I want to replace 'hello' with 'hi' and 'this' with 'its'. 
Can I do it in a single line? Or can I use back-referencing in regex for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really, since you need to call `re.sub()` and give the string to it as an argument. You'd get ugly nested calls. Instead, `str.replace()` works as method on the string itself and returns the new string, so you can chain the calls:

```
s='hello, this is me'
s=s.replace("hello", "hi").replace("this", "it's")
```

But if you have a list of replacements, you can of course loop over them even with `re.sub()`:

```
import re
s='hello, this is me'
replacements=[("hello", "hi"), ("this", "it's")]
for pat,repl in replacements:
    s = re.sub(pat, repl, s)
```

And no, regexes by themselves don't really lend to multiple replacements.

Comment: `re.sub` can take a function in place of a replacement string - the conditional logic around replacement could go into this function....

Comment: @iruvar, then you could have something like `re.sub("hello|this", func, s)` and in `func` check which word was matched, right? That doesn't sound very straightforward either... :)

Comment: ikkachu, if you convert `replacements` into a dict (`{"hello": "hi", "this": "it's"}` ), the function boils down to `def func(matchobj): return replacements.get(matchobj.group(), "")` - pretty straightforward

Comment: @iruvar, in that sense, yes. Though the matching pattern would still need to be a combination of all the patterns to be replaced, right? But anyway, that's starting to sound like an independent answer...

Comment: True. But that's easily accomplished via a `'|'.join(replacements)`. Given that this is not a programming SE site I'm unsure if a separate answer is warranted so I leave it here for the record as a comment